# Sort column2 Unix

Tags: unix, sorting

I have a problem with the Sort command in unix
I have a text file that contains line like this:

```
de la (-0.167969404167593)
de l (-0.137148984295644)
la commission (0.0922090559997898)
à la (-0.115188946405936)
à l (-0.0936395578796088)
c est (0.130628584805583)
```

I want to sort these sentence according to a descending order of the values ​​in parenthesis
I do this commande :

```
sort 2fr -t"(" -k2r > 2frsort
```

But it does not the sort correctly
Any idea please?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use numeric sort on the second column:

```
$ sort --numeric-sort --field-separator '(' --reverse --key 2 test.dat
c est (0.130628584805583)
la commission (0.0922090559997898)
à l (-0.0936395578796088)
à la (-0.115188946405936)
de l (-0.137148984295644)
de la (-0.167969404167593)
```

Comment: But i want to sort it in descending order

Comment: Okay, thise command **sort 2fr -k2n,2 -t"(" -k2r > 2frsort** does not give the right answer

Comment: there is a probleme with negatif values.  :(

Comment: what happens if you remove the parens from your file? Good luck.

Comment: de la (-0.167969404167593)
de l (-0.137148984295644)
c est (0.130628584805583)
à la (-0.115188946405936)
à l (-0.0936395578796088)
la commission (0.0922090559997898)  No there is a probleme when i make sort --reverse --key 3 test.dat

Comment: It's a big problem of scientific notation like this : "-9.5573404129472e-05"

Comment: sort --numeric-sort --field-separator '(' --reverse --key 2 test

Comment: la commission (0.0922090559997898)
de la (-0.167969404167593)
de l (-0.137148984295644)
c est (0.130628584805583)
à la (-0.115188946405936)
à l (-0.0936395578796088)
 It is not sorted :(

Answer (score 0):

Are you using GNU `sort`?  If so, `-g` option handles the exponential notation

`sort -t '(' -k 2 -g -r`